# Accessing Hadoop clusters from eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I just followed the Hadoop(0.20.2) installation tutorial and did the set up. I can run map reduce program on the cluster through eclipse. Now my problem is how can I connect to Hadoop clusters from my local system. Local system is windows 7 and I have installed eclipse plugin for Hadoop. I was trying to connect to Hadoop from my local system which is windows(My local system and Hadoop system are in same subnet). I got connection timed out error while connecting to Hadoop server.

In configuration files of Hadoop I have given actual IP addresses.
Not sure which step I have missed out?

Answer (score 0):

I recently read, that the eclipse plugin won't work at all. But you can simply connect to your Cluster with the configuration keys:

```
mapred.job.tracker 
fs.default.name
```

**EDIT:** here is a working version [Apache Jira: Eclipse Plugin does not work with Eclipse Ganymede (3.4)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1280)